# JS issue while Loading Blade View into another using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have done with loading a blade view into another using ajax. But, Javascript written in main file is not working for the loaded file. How can I overcome this issue?

bladeView

```
<span class="selectable " id="" name="">
Rate Here
</span>
```

JS in bladeMain

```
$('.selectable').click(function () {
            alert('working');
        });
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Code Updated...

Comment: Can you show your ajax code as well ? I got the issue but just checking if I can give you a better solution.

Comment: Thank you bro. Just find the solution.
    $(document).on('click', '.selectable', function () {
                alert(this.id);
            });

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution by using following Jquery function

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectable', function () {
            alert('hi');
        });
```

Comment: Yes, you got it right. The reason it wasn't working was because the event was attached when it wasn't still in the DOM and JS coundn't find the element to attach. A better solution is to write this in your ajax success function `success:function(){ ... }`

Comment: This is my Ajax. How can I put my previous code inside it. 

    success: function (data) {
                        $('#table').html(data);
                    }

Comment: See [here](https://pastebin.com/MYb3GNE8)

Comment: Got it. Thank you :-)